# Convert SHP to JSON

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, json

I need to convert shapefile to JSON in the following data structure.How can I do this?

```
{
  "field": [
    {
      "latitude": 52.8812385372,
      "longitude": 6.9287692025
    },
    {
      "latitude": 52.8770337689,
      "longitude": 6.9344024716
    },
    ...
    {
      "latitude": 52.8769081136,
      "longitude": 6.9345708129
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [tour] to learn about the focused Q&A format of this site. Then I suggest you [edit] your question to add information about what you've already researched or tried. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: Without QGIS, I'll use **GDAL** with `ogr2ogr` to convert the shapefile to geojson and after, will use a tool like **jq** for parsing and reformating geojson to the wanted json format.

Comment: If you have a shapefile and want to get a geojson out of it. You can simply put it in Qgis, then save the layer as a geojson instead of shapefile. And if you open the geojson with a text editor, you will get the information you want i think.

Comment: I have QGIS it is not problem. I have shapefile with lots of points. I can not edit lots of points in one GEOJSON. And I need JSON in specific structure. From QGIS i Can export only GEOJSON. I Will try JQ, but i dont know this tool.